# .Net Internet Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

How to declare a network proxy for all windows programs to use?

Comment: for all windows programs you make? or for all programs on your machine?

Comment: i want to use it on my ftp server in my office.
so any one should be able to use it in my network without doing any special action.

Comment: Even after your comments the question is not clear, where's the problem? Please avoid to be too generic. While you're tagging .NET and C#, there's no mention about it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET framework WebRequest use Internet Options for current user context (accessible from control panel). As if it is set for IE, it will be used by .NET WebRequest.

But when WebRequest will run under account such as "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", for example from ASP.NET application, there's no Internet Options set for this user. That way you have to play with registry.

For more, read article ["Take the Burden Off Users with Automatic Configuration in .NET"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300743.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Open IE go to internet options, go to connections, lan settings ->proxy settings

:P Not really an answer, just my tech support days shining through.

Comment: i want to use it as a filterbreaker.
so internet options cannot help me because it cannot encrypt URLs with  RSA.

Answer (score 1):

A quick [search on Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+setup+windows+internet+proxy+from+c%23%3F&go=&form=QBRE&filt=lf) brought this [post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=7573).

The guy there was able to do what you want using WMI.